# comments to editors

Tags: feature-request, editing, comments

Sombody has just edited my answer. I don't see an argument for this edit. It seems that I cannot address him in a comment though he is shown as editor. I remember similar situations

Wouldn't it make sense to include editors in the comment addressing?

Comment: This indeed came up before, I believe @Anthon suggested it, though I'm having problems finding that meta now.

Comment: According to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work, an editor will be notified with `@name`, even if the username doesn't come up in tab completion.

Comment: @slm I deleted that [feature request](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3246/expanding-username-for-the-editors-of-a-post) as it was already implemented: [Expand the username auto-completion to everyone who can be notified](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106534/186664)

Answer (score 2):

If you write `@bob` in a comment and bob edited the post, then bob will be notified of your comment. Yes, this works, even though editor names are not included in the completion list.

I think the rationale for not making this feature obvious is that commenting to an editor is discouraged, because it bothers the post author as well and it's likely to be the start of a discussion. But it is allowed, I think, mostly for the use case that you want: to allow the author to discuss an edit with the editor.

You can only ping editors that way. This includes submitters of accepted suggested edits, not submitters of pending or rejected suggested edits.