# Comments to 3rd party bounty providers

Tags: support, comments, bounty, notifications

This [question](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3267/33055) asks about how to address the editors of some question. These can be addressed with `@name` although the system will not offer completion while typing `name`.

I wanted to comment to someone that provided a bounty on some other person's Question. Can I address the bounty provider in the same way and rely on that they get an inbox message from the system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You can address [anyone who is the sole owner of an entry in the revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129232/are-bounty-placers-notified-of-comments#comment353626_129236). Besides editors, this includes bounty placers, and people who (un)protected. This also includes moderators who (unlocked), closed or reopened, but not ordinary users who cast close/reopen votes.